# Can I set the iPhone to edge network programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, settings

Is it possible to troggle between 3g and edge through an app and not closing the app and going to settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't possible via the SDK. The choice between 3G and Edge is a user choice, (provided that 3G is available and there actually is a choice) and not a programmer choice.

You may get away with it in on a jailbroken phone, but not via the official SDK.

Comment: You can most definitely do it on jailbroken phone... not just maybe.  I'm not sure how to do it, but I have software on my phone that does.